# In Access give the spacing alias in select query

Tags: c#, php, ms-access-2007

SQL aliases are used to temporarily rename a table or a column heading.

I want to give alias in select query but that not work

ex:

```
select ID,name_shop as **Shop Name**,contact_name as **Contact_Name**,contact_no as Contact_No,address as Address from purchase_party_name
```

the bold field name i want to give as the name of that field but that time use comapulsary under score that allowed to space then how??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use square brackets

```
select ID,name_shop as [Shop Name],contact_name as [Contact Name],contact_no as Contact_No,address as Address from purchase_party_name
```